# Remove text from lines matching string using batch

Tags: regex, bash, shell, batch-file, cmd

I need to remove the text from the lines that contain a specific string using batch processors: SED, AWK, Windows batch, Unix shell or something similar.
If the string is "green" then the following input

```
red
green 1
blue
green 2
yellow
```

will produce the output

```
red
<EMPTY LINE>
blue
<EMPTY LINE>
yellow
```

I also need to do the same thing for lines not matching the string, producing the output

```
<EMPTY LINE>
green 1
<EMPTY LINE>
green 2
<EMPTY LINE>
```

I need to remove text from lines (empty the content of lines), not to delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed to empty lines containing `green`:

```
sed '/green/s/.*//' input
```

And using sed to empty other lines:

```
sed '/green/!s/.*//' input
```

Comment: Another way of doing this: `sed 's/^.*green.*$//' input`.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Command Line/Batch

Use [`find`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725655%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) or [`findstr`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Output non matching lines

```
find /V "green" file.txt
```

Output matching lines

```
find "green" file.txt
```

These commands will output the content to the console. Redirect the output to destination files as needed. Example:

```
find /V "green" file.txt > nonmatchingoutput.txt
```

Type `find /?` or `findstr /?` for help and all the options.

---

**Update** for updated question.

This will do what you ask using only Batch

```
:: Hide Commands
@echo off

:: Erase Existing Files
>match.txt ( <nul set /p "=" )
>nomatch.txt ( <nul set /p "=" )

:: Loop through Source and Generate Output
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%K in ('type temp.txt ^| find /V /N ""') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%X in ('echo(%%L ^| find /V "green"') do (
        echo(%%X>>nomatch.txt
        echo.>>match.txt
    )
    for /f "delims=" %%X in ('echo(%%L ^| find "green"') do (
        echo(%%X>>match.txt
        echo.>>nomatch.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: find is like grep, it will remove the matching lines, instead of emptying them.

Answer (score 0):

Using perl:

```
# Empty when finding green
perl -pe 's,.*,, if /green/' inputfile
# Empty when not finding green
perl -pe 's,.*,, unless /green/' inputfile
```

These commands will output the content to stdout, so redirect the output to the destination files.

Comment: Why use commas in the first regex? That's just confusing.

Comment: And why not? You can use any reasonable separator. And on some keyboards, a comma is easier to type than a forward slash ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sed solutions are listed below:

**Input.txt**

```
red
green 1
blue
green 2
yellow
```

**Try This**

**Code 1 :**

```
$> grep -v green Input.txt  | sed G
```

or

```
$> sed '!s/^green//g' Input.txt

red

blue

yellow
```

**Code 2 :**

```
$> grep green Input.txt  | sed G
```

or

```
$> sed -n '/green/p' Input.txt



green 1

green 2
```